# Lost Postcard Shop

Tags: translation, meaning, meaning-in-context

I travelled to Shanghai a long time ago and recently got to come back for CPhI. I returned to Tianzifang, where I bought these beautiful poscards, and though I can speak and read some Chinese, I couldn’t relocate the shop before I had to leave. I then followed the QR code to wechat, but couldn’t figure out how to buy online. Can anyone read this text and give me a pointer about where I might find a place online to replenish my supply?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cover shows 手绘上海．外滩 hand-painting Shanghai.

The back side shows 本心书店. This is what you need.

Check the following links.

本心书店 on [挖东西](https://www.wadongxi.com/shop/2252547) and on [淘宝](https://shop67707488.world.taobao.com/).

Comment: You’re amazing. Thank you!